# Will Windows 8 support System.Device.Location?

Tags: .net, windows

I am writting Windows 7 apps using `System.Device.Location`, which depends on Windows Sensor and Location Platform. I download the Consumer preview, but I cannot find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, it's in the .NET Framework 4.5:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location(v=vs.110).aspx

However, it doesn't appear that Windows 8 *Metro* apps have this namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232(v=vs.110).aspx

However again, it *looks* like some of the classes in the `System.Device.Location` namespace have migrated to `Windows.Devices.Geolocation` namespace, which is in Metro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229921.aspx

What it **doesn't** tell you is if they are equivalent. You may not be able to just change namespaces, so some code fixing may be required. On the surface they look like they are tackling the same problem.

Comment: Hope they are staying with System.Device.Location namespace.

Comment: @KelvinFixx I doubt it. The Metro namespace choices are likely very well embedded now and I doubt much will change. However, that is different to the .NET Framework, which will remain largely the same with new stuff added.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below namespace instead

```
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
```

Answer (score -1):

The GeoLocation class would work for you !!
What it does , it would fetch you your latitude and longitude